# Move Delta from one Database to another Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

I have two identical(almost) databases in MySQL but on two different servers, I need to export **Delta** from Database 1 and import it in Database 2, schema is having M:N relationship, so what is the best way to achieve this hectic task.
Is there any **Migration** tool on which we can impose certain condition and rest it maintains the integrity of data?

Comment: is this the one time activity ? you want full database sync or only some data from some tables ?

Comment: It is one time activity, and I need to move only only some data from some tables.

Comment: you can dump (inserts) the desired rows in some file (sync.sql) and import into the target db

Comment: That I know but i was thinking if there are any migrating tools which can perform this action in a more smarter way

Answer (score 0):

I don't seen any free tool to sync dbs for your situation. SQLYog can sync db's but with full tables. But You can use SQLYog to created insert.sql files for selected rows and dump them to other db.

1. run query.
2. press ctrl + shift + E. wizard comes to save selected data.
3. select sql option
4. select only data option
5. select file to save and click export.
6. now import the created sql into the target db.